# Check if 2d Array Index Exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 8x8 2 dimensional array named `positions` and I'm trying to see if there's a way to check if an index is defined or not. I saw an example using

```
if (typeof positions[8] === "undefined") alert('undefined');
```

but when I try it using an index for a row and column like this:

```
if (typeof positions[8][0] === "undefined") alert('undefined');
```

I'm getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Is there a way to check if an index for a 2D array exists, not only for one index but for both its dimensions?

Comment: why you don't check both ?

Comment: Can you give an example, Im not quite sure what ur saying, thanks.

Comment: if ((typeof positions[8] === "undefined")  || (typeof positions[8][0] === "undefined")) alert('undefined');

Comment: `if (Array.isArray(positions[8]) && typeof positions[8][0] === "undefined")` or use typeof for both check

Comment: So what's the difference between the second part in your example after the '&&' and what I tried?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the row doesn't exist you cannot access elements in it.

A solution is

```
if ((positions[8]||[])[0] === undefined) { ... }
```

the idea is that `undefined` is falsy, thus `position[8]||[]` will return an empty list if row 8 is not present and the second indexing will not raise an error.

The formal problem of that expression is that in case `position[8]` is indeed `undefined` a new temporary empty row is allocated just to try to access it. This could be in theory solved by a smart-enough compiler (and may be it is in some implementation) but another option without this temporary allocation could instead be

```
if (!position[8] || position[8][0] === undefined) { ... }
```

where he problem is instead that both `position` and `[8]` inside the result are looked up twice (if `position` is a global this can require a dictionary lookup and, even worse than that, accessing `position[8]` can potentially change what `position` will resolve to in next lookup if `position` is for example a proxy).
An even more explicit

```
{
  let row = position[8];
  if (row === undefined || row[0] === undefined) { ... }
}
```

should AFAIK solve these problems but is however even more verbose and hard to read and probably a bad idea in most cases.

PS: given the general orientation of Javascript of just returning `undefined` and keeping running it's indeed surprising that `undefined[...]` wasn't defined to be `undefined` itself instead of raising an error.

PPS: this problem of accessing an element in a potentially non-existent array, field in a potentially non-existent object or calling a potentially non-existing function is becoming popular and may be in a few months there will be (or there already is) a proposal about adding something like `position[?8]===undefined` to mean exactly this kind of somewhat common computation. But as far as I know this didn't make it into Javascript (yet).

Comment: Your explanation really makes sense to me, thanks! I see other people comparing it to a string "undefined" and you're just comparing it to undefined, is that the same thing?

Comment: @MarksCode: they compare the result of `typeof` with the string `"undefined"` (`typeof` operator returns a string). I prefer to use strict equality `===` with `undefined` instead of using `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check both arrays for elements existence, but this approach is shorter:

```
if (!(8 in positions && 0 in positions[8])) alert('undefined');
```

[Check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) more about `in` operator.